# website showing index.php file data

Tags: php, .htaccess

When I access to my website domain in browser ,it showing code of index.php.I moved this site from old server to new server.And then,I set new server IP address in my host file.After that,I access it.But ,it showing coding.How can I do that?Please help me kindly.

**This is my .htaccess file**

```
  php_value error_reporting 039
  php_flag display_errors On

 DirectoryIndex _index.php index.php
```

**This is output**

```
    <?php
    define("NO_IFRAME_DEFINE", "defined");
    // ini_set("display_errors", "1");
    // error_reporting(E_ERROR);
    require_once("init.php");

    $mb_flg = 0;
    $mb_url = $ROOT_URL."/i/";

    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){

        $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        if(eregi("DoCoMo",$user_agent)){$mb_flg = 1;}
        if(eregi("UP\.Browser",$user_agent)){$mb_flg = 1;}
        if(eregi("J-PHONE",$user_agent)){$mb_flg = 1;}
        if(eregi("Vodafone",$user_agent)){$mb_flg = 1;}
        if(eregi("SoftBank",$user_agent)){$mb_flg = 1;}
        if(eregi("J-EMULATOR",$user_agent)){$mb_flg = 1;}

        if($mb_flg == 1){
            header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
            header("Location: $mb_url");
        }
    }
........
?>
```

Comment: Seems like either Apache is misconfigured or PHP isn't even installed. Probably the latter.

Comment: Please can you let us know what do you see? What is the output when you go to the index page?

Comment: It showing php coding of index.php.

Comment: Can you at least put some part of the output? Honestly, it's difficult to tell if you don't let us know the error message on the screen (or the output of the screen).

Comment: Have you made sure your index.php has the opening <?php tags...

Comment: Which system are you on? Which operating system, which PHP, which Apache? Are you usng LAMP stack, or XAMPP?

Comment: I am using xampp.

Comment: Is your xampp correctly working? You can see the green lights for apache in XAMPP control panel?

Answer (score 1):

From what given now, I can only assume that the apache is not working properly. Or that PHP is not set up properly. Check your Apache and PHP configurations.Try restarting Apache, after that, if that didn't help, try reinstalling PHP.

Comment: Try reinstalling XAMPP in your case, and see that Apache will start up correctly, showing green light in XAMPP Control Panel.